# Explain this 'Merge' Function in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, mergesort

I am learning Haskell and I am having trouble understanding this function.  I am implementing mergesort.  I have the mergesort recursive function implemented, but I don't understand what this 'merge' function is doing.  I understand merge sort in an imperative language, but I don't understand the syntax here.

```
merge []         ys                   = ys
merge xs         []                   = xs
merge xs@(x:xt) ys@(y:yt) | x <= y    = x : merge xt ys
                          | otherwise = y : merge xs yt
```

Comment: From what I see this function merges two sorted lists, and returns a sorted list. What is it that you don't understand? Is it the syntax?

Comment: see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords#.40.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
merge []         ys                   = ys
```

If the first argument is empty, give the second argument.

```
merge xs         []                   = xs
```

If the second argument is empty, give the first argument.

```
merge xs@(x:xt) ys@(y:yt) | x <= y    = x : merge xt ys
                          | otherwise = y : merge xs yt
```

If `x` is smaller than or equal to `y`, cons (add to the front) x to the result of merging the rest of `xs` (which is `xt`) with `ys`. Otherwise `y` was smaller, so cons it to the result of merging xs with the rest of `ys` (which is `yt`).

`xs@(x:xt)` is parameter destructuring using a "placeholder". The result is that `xs` will refer to the entire first argument, while `x` is the head and `xt` is the tail.

Since merge is recursively defined, it will continue to cons elements from xs and ys until at least one is empty and then simply return it.

The bars (|) signify ["guards"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards), which let you define conditions in a nice and succinct manner.

Comment: What about the xs@(x:xt) and ys@(y:yt) signature?

Comment: @csreap3r added explanation of placeholder

Comment: So are the use of the 'pipes' basically conditional statements?

Comment: Yes! They are called "guards"

Comment: @csreap3r I recommend reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/ which is a marvelous book

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down line by line:

1. `merge [] ys = ys`

   This line pattern matches on the first list. If the first list is an empty list (i.e. `[]`), then return the second list.
2. `merge xs [] = xs`

   Same as before, only with the lists role reversed.
3. `merge xs@(x:xt) ys@(y:yt)`

   A pattern match like `(x:xt)` matches only if the list element is non-empty. If it matches `x` is set to the first element, and `xt` is set to the rest of a list. Remember that `:` is the list constructor operator (i.e., `1 : [2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]`).
   The `xs@...` prefix means that whole list is set to `xs`. This is useful if you need refer to the whole list as well as to its head and tail, at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The function pattern matches on both of it's arguments. Let's look at each of the individual clauses:

```
merge []         ys                   = ys
```

So, merging an empty list and another list ys results in ys.

```
merge xs         []                   = xs
```

This is like the first clause, just the other way around: merging a list xs and an empty list gives xs.

```
merge xs@(x:xt) ys@(y:yt) | x <= y    = x : merge xt ys
                          | otherwise = y : merge xs yt
```

This is the recursive clause. Here the function pattern matches on both of it's arguments, so that:

- `xs` is the first list, and is deconstructed (via an as-pattern) into the head `x` and the tail `xt`
- `ys` is the second list, which is deconstructed into it's head `y` and it's tail `yt`.

Now, if the head of the first list is smaller or equal than the head of the second list (first guard), then the result is just the head of the first list `y` followed by the result of merging the tail of the first list (this is `xt`) and the second list `ys`. We do the opposite if `y` smaller greater than `x`.